# Testing Chargebacks/Dispute with IPN in the PayPal Sandbox

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-ipn

Is there any way to go to test Chargebacks/Disputes on the PayPal Sandbox test site?

I try to use the resolution center to create new cases both through the normal method of disputing a charge and through the sandbox specific "Create or Resolve Case" section of the Resolution Center.

Either way I do it, I can only ever get the disputes into a status of "Being Reviewed By PayPal".  No IPN notifications are sent out.

This support article details the expected steps I'm hoping to emulate in the sandbox environment: https://ppmts.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/622/kw/Dispute

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you'll need to do is create your own IPN simulator to test this.  You can make a basic HTML form with the action set to your IPN URL and hidden fields that match the names/values you expect to get from an IPN.

This way you can load your test in a browser and submit it to your IPN listener.  You'll be able to see the results on screen which can help with troubleshooting.

Keep in mind that when testing this way the data is not coming from PayPal's server so the IPN will be unverified.  You'll need to make sure your code logic handles that.

Here are some samples of IPN's you'd get when a chargeback occurs so you can see what you should expect and setup your simulator accordingly.

**New Case**

```
txn_type = new_case
payment_date = 13:40:52 Aug 05, 2013 PDT
case_id = PP-002-576-509-683
receipt_id = 4674-2219-3481-3741
case_type = chargeback
business = payments@domain.com
verify_sign = AeD56uUedZzgp83xxTHMkZtMZ9FVAzvpMwl6OHUf9CNvlvgA2P0mbcwP
payer_email = 9FE47613HE5558457@dcc.paypal.com
txn_id = 0PC8014855508203X
case_creation_date = 18:40:23 Sep 04, 2013 PDT
receiver_email = payments@domain.com
payer_id = RZ3LX555U646Q
receiver_id = M5VRA555CSK6
reason_code = non_receipt
custom = 
charset = windows-1252
notify_version = 3.7
ipn_track_id = 2842c24f40ac
```

**Reversal**

```
mc_gross = -1972.86
protection_eligibility = Ineligible
payer_id = RZ3LX555U646Q
address_street = N/A
payment_date = 18:42:00 Sep 04, 2013 PDT
payment_status = Reversed
charset = windows-1252
address_zip = 00000
first_name = Tester
mc_fee = -44.74
address_country_code = US
address_name = Tester Testerson
notify_version = 3.7
reason_code = chargeback
custom = 
business = payments@usbswiper.com
address_country = United States
address_city = NA
verify_sign = Ai1PaghZh5FmBLCDCTQpwG8jB264ABWpa3tbhFljkaPnVj1L9ip5EwyS
parent_txn_id = 0PC8014555008203X
txn_id = 0PC8014855508203X
payment_type = instant
last_name = Testerson
address_state = NA
receiver_email = payments@domain.com
payment_fee = -44.74
receiver_id = M5VRA555CSK6
item_name = PayPal POS Web Order
mc_currency = USD
item_number = 
residence_country = US
receipt_id = 4674-2219-3481-3741
handling_amount = 0.00
transaction_subject = 
payment_gross = -1972.86
shipping = 100.00
ipn_track_id = f456d076de1ff
```

Comment: I've already done that with the simulator (https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/applications/ipn_simulator).  I was really hoping there would be a way to test this whole process from start to finish as if it were on production.

Comment: May I ask if these examples are based on some real scenario? Or you made using the simulator?

Comment: These examples are from a real scenario.  I just replaced some of the actual data with bogus data, but the format is exactly the same.